# TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED Adding New Pool to Uniswap

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I created a new ERC20 token and I'm trying to create a new pool ETH pair with my token on Uniswap V2.  However, when I get to the last step on Uniswap and press "Add" it doesn't do anything.  When I look at my browser console I see the following errors:

> Object { code: -32603, message: "execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED", data: {…} }

and I also get

> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Can anyone help me?  My contract can be found here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0c6891f1bbc03805585d70b2170d9e84dbceee00#code#L646

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I'll post back here if I solve it.

Comment: Hey, sorry I never posted a update, but I was able to fix it by adding a APPROVE in the thransferFrom function.  I'm on mobile at the moment, but I cant add a more elegant solution for you when I get to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

In my TransferFrom function I added the following and it resolved my issue.

```
if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) 
{
    require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
    
    unchecked
    {
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by approving the contract and then do TranasferFrom().